# Select first k elements in C# LINQ such that the sum of elements is less than S

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of numbers and a variable S. I want to select first k elements out of them using LINQ in C# such that the sum of k elements is less than S.

For example:

int[] Numbers = { 1, 4, 53, 23, 15, 12, 15, 25, 45, 13, 16, 76, 43, 82, 24 };
int S = 100;

The result would be an array: {1, 4, 53, 23, 15}

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [TakeWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
int[] Numbers = { 1, 4, 53, 23, 15, 12, 15, 25, 45, 13, 16, 76, 43, 82, 24 };    
int total = 0;
var result = Numbers.TakeWhile(i =>
                     {
                         total += i;
                         return total < s
                     });
```